# Tablet shows "Low on memory" warning even though internal memory is greatly empty

Tags: storage, ram

My tablet shows `Low on memory` with `Total 0.98 GB, 750 MB used` even though internal memory is `Total 13.65 GB, 13.65GB free`

Comment: I guess that thosse 13 GB are on sd card, right?

Answer (score 0):

The internal memory is split into partitions, one of them is `/system`, which I believe is the one with 13.65 GB in size, this one is mounted read-only, meaning you can't install apps on it.

Another partition is `/data` (the 0.98 GB maybe, i'm not sure though), it is mounted read-write, and it's where apps are installed.

I think there is an option to install apps directly into external storage (your SD card) or at least relocate them from `/data` partition into SD card.

Yet another option, is to root your device and allocate more space to `/data` partition.